# VHDL: Are if-else and case statements supposed to synthesize the same hardware?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, synthesis

The if-else and case statements are equivalent. The later maybe easier to read when we have a lot of possibilities being checked.

A conditional is supposed to infer mux in hardware. However, there is different between having a chain of 2-to-1 mux and a big n-to-1 mux doing the same thing in terms of propagation delay.

Is the if-else statement and case statement supposed to infer the **same** hardware? Or is there some difference in how they would be synthesized?

Comment: yes... there is a "bug" in APA synthesis such that a large if/elseif/... will produce a massive cascaded AND network to achieve this, eating LUT & increased propogation delay. Why not use a case statement if you have a lot of possibilities to check

Comment: Just look under the "[RTL view](http://surf-vhdl.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/mux4-rtl-viewer.jpg)" after you've synthesized. It will show you how the *compiler* put it together.

Comment: Contrary to what you might read below, a synthesis vendor can do anything which conforms to the *simulation* semantics of the language; their output will then, by definition, be correct, period. Having said that, when I taught this stuff I told students to expect a mux in one case and a priority encoder/chain in the other.

Answer (score 3):

No: if-else is sequential; case is concurrent. A single if followed by an else will be equivalent to a two input multiplexer. An if followed by if else statements is equivalent to a series of two input multiplexers like this:
[image: mux]
This is because the order you check the conditions of the if-else matters, i.e. you have priority.

A case statement, on the other hand is concurrent. Everything happens at the same time.

Comment: I would just add a note that multiplexers themselves are not really a thing in an FPGA, LUTs are, so a schematic rendering multiplexers is not particularly diagnostic of what will be actually be done in terms of space utilisation on the FPGA fabric. Modern FPGAs often have 6 input LUTs so the above will in fact collapse to two LUTs in all probability.

Comment: @DanMills I agree in general. However, modern FPGAs can have as few as 4 inputs to their LUTs, e.g. MAX 10, Cyclone V. Additionally, it is good practice to write code that scales. Every code standard I’ve seen requires you to use cases where priority is not required. There is simply no need to use if-else in most cases. You also need to consider what happens when you change hardware or go for an ASIC implementation.

Comment: Case is not a concurrent statement... The concurrent version of case is a with/select "statement". The real name is selected signal assignment. It's a special case that if/elsif/else and case statements are inferred as multiplexers. It's only true if the same output is assigned in the branches or in the choices of a case statement. The difference between if and case is that if can create a priority logic, whereas choices in a case a equally weighted.

Answer (score 1):

Neither statement necessarily maps to a multiplexer.

The HDL code is compiled to an intermediate form, which is optimized both by simplifying statements (e.g. eliminating tautologies) and by finding an optimal mapping to actual hardware that also takes propagation delays into account.

For example

```
if(input)
then
    output <= '1';
end if;
```

will probably be optimized to `output <= '1';` by the compiler, because the initial state is undefined, and a fixed value uses the least resources. Place&Route then takes this further and configures the output driver for the fixed value, so not even a single register is used.

Propagation delays need to be factored into your design where interfaces expect data to arrive on a particular clock edge, so it should have been part of the interface specification already.

For example, when I build an FIR filter, I also generate a `valid` signal that is set when steady state is reached after a reset, and a `marker` signal that is simply a delay on input markers. The obvious implementation generates `valid` \$N_{taps}\$ after reset, and the marker delay is \$\frac{N_{taps}}{2}\$, but that is not guaranteed in the interface. If I can get better pipelining behavior by adding more register stages in the middle, I can do so without breaking any connected components, and the logic is almost always simply optimized out when the compiler determines that the total delay is fixed at compile time.

Comment: Given your example and no further assignment to `output` will result in a latch... Incomplete assignment descriptions result in memory elements.

Comment: @Paebbels Only true in a combinational context. It's just a code snippet, it's pointless to nitpick.

Comment: @Paebbels, yes, if you don't run the optimizer over the design. The optimizer will see that there is a latch with a state that is either `'1'` or `'U'`, simplifies that to `'1'`, propagates the fixed value through to the output buffer and eliminates the latch, the table in front of it, and the interconnect to the output buffer.

Comment: This is not correct. At first there is no `U` value in synthese. Only `0`, `1`, `Z` and `-`. At second let's assume you incomplete code is part of a combinational process, then output is inferred to a latch. Let us assume further that output was either uninitialized (`U`) or initialized to `0`, then your latch does only one state change when input goes high. This only case where synthese can optimize output to a constant is if output was initialized to `1`. That is very unlikely.... .

Comment: Even when you put your code into a clocked process, synthese will infer the same behavior but use a flip flop instead of a latch! If you don't believe me, then write an example code for any synthese tool and send it to my email address. I'll file this behavior as a bug for you :).

Comment: @jalalipop The happens in clocked processes. The difference is you get a flip flop but never a multiplexer.

Comment: @Paebbels, I agree that a latch would be generated, but the optimizer will remove it again because the only defined value the output can take is `'1'`. My point is that the optimizer will do larger changes than the difference between `if` and `case` could ever be.

Comment: No it can not be removed/optimized on FPGAs (we are discussing an FPGA question based on the labeling of this question). This is a latch with initial value `0` that needs a high active event on `input`. If the event is never provided, `output` can stage low for ever. Usually, such latch (or more likely flip flop) are use to record startup conditions.

Comment: @Paebbels, signals do not have default values in synthesis. Thet's why you need an explicit reset signal.

Comment: No that again not correct. Please read [IEEE Std. 1076.6-2004](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1076.6-2004.html) (commonly known as VHDL Synthesis standard). It describes how default values on signals are translated to initial values of registers or latches. The standard was withdrawn by IEEE, but Altera/Intel, Synopsys and Xilinx adhere to that part of the standard. Full disclosure: I'm one of the vice-chairs of the [P1076 VSAG](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/WebHome) :).

Comment: @Paebbels True, I guess your overall point was that the way the code is written wouldn't be optimized as Simon said, which makes sense to me.

Comment: @Paebbels, tested on Quartus Prime 16.1, compiling for EP4CE22E22C8 with [this](http://paste.debian.net/992471/) test code: the RTL viewer shows `'output'` being hardwired to `1h`. This remains true even if I [extend](http://paste.debian.net/992472/) this with a local signal that is initialized to `'0'`.

Comment: @Paebbels, I did manage to create a latch by making the process sensitive to `input` — in this case, the `if` is still optimized out, and the flip flop's D input is connected to `1`, but now the input is connected to the FF's clock input.

Comment: I can not reproduce your results in Quartus Prime 17.0. RTL Viewer and Technology Map Viewer show the behavior as described by me. I tested flip flops and latches as well as no init value, init to `0` and init to `1`. If `output` is initialized to `1` then optimization removes the memory element as expected. I'm very sure that I used this feature years back in Quartus II 13.0.